# Sort price with currency symbol in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a price field in table which has price as

```
$5000
$500
$6000
$4000
```

I want to sort them in ascending order.

I tried

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX('price', '$', 1),
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`price`, '$', -1) AS SIGNED)
```

but its not working.

Comment: Do yourself a massive favour. DON'T store the '$'

Comment: Downvote reason #1: "it's not working" doesn't help anyone to see how it's not working. Downvote reason #2 - data types exist for a reason, especially numeric ones where you store **numbers** so you can sort them and perform mathematical operations on them. Solution to your problem is what Strawberry wrote. I'd suggest you include how something doesn't work next time you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '$', -1) AS SIGNED)
FROM test
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select '$400' cur                                                                                     
    -> union                                                                                                                           
    -> select '$600' cur                                                                                                               
    -> union                                                                                                                           
    -> select '$200' cur) t                                                                                                            
    -> order by substring(cur,2) desc;
```

In short, substring in order by clause. So, you should be writing your query something like

```
SELECT column1,column2 from your table 
order by substring(currency_column,2) desc|asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT price FROM test order by CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '$', -1) AS SIGNED)